# Define newcommand with multiple sorted mandatory arguments that can be empty

Tags: macros, optional-arguments

I'm trying to define a command that will take 3 arguments each one possibly empty. An empty argument will slightly modify the output. Let me give a non-working example :

```
\newcommand{\foo}[3]{
\textbf{bar}(
  \ifthenelse{\isempty{#1}}
    {}
    {#1, }
    #2)
    \ifthenelse{\isempty{#3}}
    {}
    {\cap #3}
}
```

And this is what I would like to get :

- `\foo{a}{b}{c}` => [image: foo1]
- `\foo{}{b}{}` => [image: foo2]
- `\foo{}{b}{c}` => [image: foo3]

But obviously it doesn't work. I'd like, as much as possible, to call this function with only one type of bracket (since I will always write the 3 pairs of bracket even if they are empty). As far as I'm concern, I consider that there's no optional arguments in it, only mandatory arguments that are possibly empty. I pretty sure I'm not doing things right but I really don't get the idea of this `\newcommand` function.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While `xparse` is one way to go, here's another approach:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\foo[3]{%%
  \textbf{bar}(%%
  \expandafter\ifx\expandafter\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
  \else
    #1,
  \fi 
  #2)
  \expandafter\ifx\expandafter\relax\detokenize{#3}\relax
  \else
  \cap#3
  \fi}


\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}

  $\foo{a}{b}{c}$

  $\foo{}{b}{}$

  $\foo{}{b}{c}$

\end{document}
```

[image]
The `\expandafter\ifx\expandafter\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax` is a nice way of testing for an empty argument to your macro.  Essentially if `#1` is empty, then the `\detokenize{#1}` essentially vanishes and the test becomes

```
\ifx\relax\relax
```

which will test to true.

If `#1` is not empty, then `\detokenize` will result in a token that is not going to result in a true value when compared with `\relax`.

To make your code a little more readable, you could define your own test commnad sequence:

```
\newcommand\aeifempty[3]{%%
  \expandafter\ifx\expandafter\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    #2%%
  \else
    #3%%
  \fi}
```

and then your `\foo` could be written as

```
\newcommand\foo[3]{%%
  \textbf{bar}(%%
  \aeifempty{#1}{}{#1,}%%
  #2)
  \aeifempty{#3}{}{\cap#3}}
```

Comment: `\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax` is as good and simpler

Comment: By the way, the spacing around the intersection symbol is wrong.

Comment: @egreg  Hmm.  I hadn't paid attention to that.  But, now that I see it, I wonder why.  Do I need to `{}` around it so it behaves as a binary operation?

Comment: @egreg  I see the problem!!

Answer (score 3):

If you use `xparse`, you need not define your own test for emptyness:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\ifnotblank}{mm}
 {
  \tl_if_blank:nF { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{mmm}
 {%
  \operatorname{\mathbf{bar}}(\ifnotblank{#1}{#1,}#2)%
  \ifnotblank{#3}{\cap #3}%
 }

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{@{}ll@{}}
\verb|\foo{a}{b}{c}| & $\foo{a}{b}{c}$ \\
\verb|\foo{}{b}{}|   & $\foo{}{b}{}$ \\
\verb|\foo{}{b}{c}|  & $\foo{}{b}{c}$ \\
\verb|\foo{ }{b}{ }| & $\foo{}{b}{}$ \\
\verb|\foo{ }{b}{c}| & $\foo{}{b}{c}$
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The function `\tl_if_blank:nF` returns the second argument if and only if the first argument is not blank (a sequence of zero or more blank spaces).

[image]

Of course, for the particular application just *two* arguments would be needed:

```
\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{mm}{%
  \operatorname{\mathbf{bar}}(#1)%
  \notblank{#2}{\cap#2}%
}
```

and `\foo{a,b}{c}`, `\foo{b}{c}` or `\foo{b}{}` would do.

Answer (score 2):

With `xparse` and `\NewDocumentCommand` it is possible to define a macro with two *optional* and one *mandatory* argument, where the latter is the middle one:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand{\foo}{ o m o }{%
   \text{bar}(%
   \IfValueT{#1}{#1,}%
   #2)%
   \IfValueT{#3}{\cap #3}%
}

\begin{document}
$\foo[a]{b}[c]$

$\foo{b}$

$\foo[a]{b}$

$\foo{b}[c]$
\end{document}
```

*But* this definition can be problematic if the command is followed by a literal `[` the is part of the equation. In that case there must be a space between the mandatory argument and the opening bracket:

```
$\foo{b} [x,y,z]$
```

Comment: I believe with `xparse` a following `[` shouldn't be a problem if there is a space before it.

Comment: @A.Ellett: indeed :-) I changed my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The OP didn't say what packages, if any, were used.

The OP's code works for me with `\usepackage{xifthen}`.

It doesn't work with `\usepackage{ifthen}`, which doesn't implement `\isempty`.

With `\usepackage{ifthen}`, you can do

```
\newcommand{\foo}[3]{
\textbf{bar}(
  \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}
    {}
    {#1, }
    #2)
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#3}{}}
    {}
    {\cap #3}
}
```

but the `xifthen` version is more efficient because `\isempty` doesn't expand its argument, but `\equal` does.